# How am I failing to add an item to a list?

Tags: python, cgi

I have an old-fashioned Python CGI script that is intended to allow an arbitrary number of saved questions, and allow each question an arbitrary number of saved answers. I have been trying to save a second answer for a test question by making it index 1 on a list, but the (intended) assignment does not seem to be doing anything.

The function to parse CGI values (the value not being saved is `saved_0_2`) is,

```
def save_values():
    sys.stderr.write('save_values()\n')
    if get_cgi('submitted'):
        sys.stderr.write('submitted')
        sys.stderr.write(repr(cgi_form.keys()) + '\n')
        for key in cgi_form.keys():
            try:
                parts = key.split('_')
                entry = int(parts[1])
                slot = int(parts[2])
                if slot == 0:
                    saved['entries'][entry][1] = get_cgi(key)
                else:
                    sys.stderr.write('Entry: ' + str(entry))
                    sys.stderr.write('Slot: ' + str(slot))
                    sys.stderr.write(get_cgi(key))
                    sys.stderr.write(repr(saved['entries'][entry][2]))
                    saved['entries'][entry][2][slot - 1] = get_cgi(key)
                    sys.stderr.write(repr(saved['entries'][entry][2]))
            except IndexError:
                pass
        saved['index'] += 1
        sys.stderr.write(repr(saved) + '\n')
        cPickle.dump(saved, open(STORAGE + '.' + str(os.getpid()), 'w'))
        os.rename(STORAGE + '.' + str(os.getpid()), STORAGE)
    if get_cgi('entry'):
        open(ACCESS, 'a').write('Statement: ' +
          saved['entries'][int(get_cgi('entry'))][1] + '\n' + 'Response: ' +
          get_cgi('response') + '\n\n')
```

The output in Apache's log, with `saved_0_2` populated with "It is.", is:

```
[Sat Jun 23 13:07:57.215372 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 2443:tid 2995739456] [client 127.0.0.1:41156] AH01215: Starting...: /home/paul/paulshukin.com/empathy_edit.cgi, referer: http://localhost/empathy_edit.cgi
[Sat Jun 23 13:07:57.219428 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 2443:tid 2995739456] [client 127.0.0.1:41156] AH01215: load_saved(): /home/paul/paulshukin.com/empathy_edit.cgi, referer: http://localhost/empathy_edit.cgi
[Sat Jun 23 13:07:57.219710 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 2443:tid 2995739456] [client 127.0.0.1:41156] AH01215: save_values(): /home/paul/paulshukin.com/empathy_edit.cgi, referer: http://localhost/empathy_edit.cgi
[Sat Jun 23 13:07:57.219842 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 2443:tid 2995739456] [client 127.0.0.1:41156] AH01215: submitted: /home/paul/paulshukin.com/empathy_edit.cgi, referer: http://localhost/empathy_edit.cgi
[Sat Jun 23 13:07:57.220047 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 2443:tid 2995739456] [client 127.0.0.1:41156] AH01215: ['saved_0_0', 'saved_0_1', 'saved_0_2', 'submitted']: /home/paul/paulshukin.com/empathy_edit.cgi, referer: http://localhost/empathy_edit.cgi
[Sat Jun 23 13:07:57.220188 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 2443:tid 2995739456] [client 127.0.0.1:41156] AH01215: Entry: 0: /home/paul/paulshukin.com/empathy_edit.cgi, referer: http://localhost/empathy_edit.cgi
[Sat Jun 23 13:07:57.220274 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 2443:tid 2995739456] [client 127.0.0.1:41156] AH01215: Slot: 1: /home/paul/paulshukin.com/empathy_edit.cgi, referer: http://localhost/empathy_edit.cgi
[Sat Jun 23 13:07:57.220370 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 2443:tid 2995739456] [client 127.0.0.1:41156] AH01215: Times are HARD.: /home/paul/paulshukin.com/empathy_edit.cgi, referer: http://localhost/empathy_edit.cgi
[Sat Jun 23 13:07:57.220463 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 2443:tid 2995739456] [client 127.0.0.1:41156] AH01215: ['Times are HARD.']: /home/paul/paulshukin.com/empathy_edit.cgi, referer: http://localhost/empathy_edit.cgi
[Sat Jun 23 13:07:57.220563 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 2443:tid 2995739456] [client 127.0.0.1:41156] AH01215: ['Times are HARD.']: /home/paul/paulshukin.com/empathy_edit.cgi, referer: http://localhost/empathy_edit.cgi
[Sat Jun 23 13:07:57.220643 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 2443:tid 2995739456] [client 127.0.0.1:41156] AH01215: Entry: 0: /home/paul/paulshukin.com/empathy_edit.cgi, referer: http://localhost/empathy_edit.cgi
[Sat Jun 23 13:07:57.220733 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 2443:tid 2995739456] [client 127.0.0.1:41156] AH01215: Slot: 2: /home/paul/paulshukin.com/empathy_edit.cgi, referer: http://localhost/empathy_edit.cgi
[Sat Jun 23 13:07:57.220811 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 2443:tid 2995739456] [client 127.0.0.1:41156] AH01215: It is.: /home/paul/paulshukin.com/empathy_edit.cgi, referer: http://localhost/empathy_edit.cgi
[Sat Jun 23 13:07:57.220901 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 2443:tid 2995739456] [client 127.0.0.1:41156] AH01215: ['Times are HARD.']: /home/paul/paulshukin.com/empathy_edit.cgi, referer: http://localhost/empathy_edit.cgi
[Sat Jun 23 13:07:57.221079 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 2443:tid 2995739456] [client 127.0.0.1:41156] AH01215: {'index': 41, 'entries': [[0, "It's tough.", ['Times are HARD.']]]}: /home/paul/paulshukin.com/empathy_edit.cgi, referer: http://localhost/empathy_edit.cgi
```

But the page loads next time without an index 1 element to the array with the existing answer. Furthermore, in the save routine, I'm being hit by the government economist computer virus. Everything says I have the value I want to in order for a second (index 1) element to be added to the list, but the assignment does not seem to change the list, and this is before pickling and saving.

Thanks for any help...

Comment: can you add a sample input + desired output? It's kind of hard to understand what this script is intended to do